# C++ operator "::" usage in standard template library while allocating iterator objects

Tags: c++

```
vector <int>::iterator itr1;
```

How do I explain this line?

`itr1` is object of class `iterator`, that is clear, but what about the prefix `vector <int>::` ?

Comment: No, the class is `std::vector<int>::iterator`. The fully qualified name matters.

Comment: It's _scope resolution operator_. What it means, that this `iterator` class is a member of `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: It's `vector`s `iterator` member type - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: What does your C++ book say about this? Is there something in your book's explanation that you do not understand. If so, you need to quote the explanation from your book, and indicate which part of it you do not understand.

Comment: Well, It's easy to figure out that it is a scope resolution operator. But with my limited knowledge of C++, I presumed that this operator is used access the member *objects* of the class, not the member class definition to declare a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::` operator is the [*Scope Resolution Operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator).

> ... what about the prefix "vector ::" ?

In the context of `vector<int>::iterator itr1;`, **the prefix to `::` is the class of which `iterator` belongs to as a [*member typedef*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class)**. Inside the [declaration of *class template* `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/vector) it would look like this:

```
template <class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> >
class vector {
public:
    // types:
    ...
    typedef ... iterator;
    ...
};
```

Hence, saying that

> ... `itr1` is object of class `iterator` [...]

would be incorrect. The class of `itr1` is `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Just [`std::iterator` is a different class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator), not necessarily unrelated to your code snippet, as it might be some base of `std::vector<int>::iterator`, but definitely not the same class.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it clearly! Just wondering, is it possible to look at the definition of std::vector<int>::iterator ?

Comment: @ashish Of course friend, just locate your `vector` header file on your disk and open it to see what's under `template <...> class vector`. Some IDEs would enable you to right click the `#include <vector>` directive and select something like *Go to file / Open file* or something along these lines : )

Comment: Thanks @SkepticalEmpiricist

Comment: Dear downvoter -- how about letting me know why this is a bad answer, given it seem to have fully helped the OP and apparently some other people found it useful too. Are you using the voting mechanism as intended? If so please clarify so I could improve this answer.